# How to change value on button press using ForEach Identifiable SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am developing the app for IOS and I am the first time using SwiftUI, just a beginner.
The problem is that I try to change the values of Text() by button click that are made by using ForEach Identifiable. Everything is nice but this is the only thing that I cannot do and find an answer for my self on internet.

[This is the view of application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21SZI.png)

Here is my code

```
import SwiftUI

private struct SizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
  static var defaultValue: CGSize = .zero
  static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) {}
}

public struct SemaphoreFlags: View {
    @State private var headerHeight = CGSize()
    
    public var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            
            Image("background")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(maxWidth: UIScreen.screenWidth, maxHeight: UIScreen.screenHeight )
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
            
                VStack{
                    
                    Image("header_inv")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(maxWidth: UIScreen.screenWidth ,alignment: .top)
                        .opacity(0.0)
                        .readSize {
                            height in headerHeight = height
                        }.padding(.bottom, 16)
                    
                    Text("HEADER TEXT")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.system(size: 24))
                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.screenWidth - 25, height: UIScreen.screenWidth / 6, alignment: .center)
                        .background(Color(red: 0.29, green: 0.67, blue: 0.88))
                        .padding(.bottom, 4.0)
                    
                    ScrollView{
                        Text(NSLocalizedString("BeaufortScale_Description", comment: "BeaufortScale_Description"))
                            .font(.system(size: 20))
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .padding(.horizontal,8)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .frame(width: .infinity, height: .infinity)
                        
                    }
                    
                    Image("blank")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.screenWidth - 25, height: UIScreen.screenWidth / 2, alignment: .center)
                    
                    
                    Text("BottomLETTER")
                        .font(.system(size: UIScreen.screenWidth/6))
                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.09, green: 0.30, blue: 0.47))
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.screenWidth, height: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false){
                        HStack{
                            ForEach(semaphoreButtonPropsData) { item in
                                semaphoreFlagsButton(SemaphoreButtonProps: item)
                            }
                        }
                    }.clipped().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom).padding(.vertical)

                }.frame(width: .infinity, height: .infinity)
            
            
            
            Image("header")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(maxWidth: UIScreen.screenWidth, maxHeight: UIScreen.screenHeight ,alignment: .top)
                
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Button (action: gotoMenu, label: {
                        Image("back")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 32, height: headerHeight.height)
                            .padding(.leading, 16.0)
                            
                    })
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            
        }.background(Color(red: 0.09, green: 0.30, blue: 0.47).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
    }
}

struct SemaphoreFlags_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SemaphoreFlags()
    }
}

struct semaphoreFlagsButton: View {
    var SemaphoreButtonProps: semaphoreButtonProps
    var body: some View {
        Button(action:{
           // ACTION TO CHANGE THE VALUES OF DESIGN 
                        (HEADER TEXT, DESCRIPTION, IMAGE, BOTTOM LETTER)

        }, label: {
            Text(SemaphoreButtonProps.buttonLetter)
                .font(.system(size: 26))
                .fontWeight(.light)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                .padding(.all, 4.0)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .frame(width: .infinity, height: 50, alignment: .center)
            
        })
            .frame(width: 100, height: 50 , alignment: .center)
            .background(Color(red: 0.29, green: 0.67, blue: 0.88))
            .cornerRadius(12)
            .padding(.leading, 8)
    }
}

struct semaphoreButtonProps: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var headerText: String
    var description: String
    var image: Image
    var bottomLetter: String
    var buttonLetter: String
}

let semaphoreButtonPropsData = [
    semaphoreButtonProps(headerText: "About",
                         description: NSLocalizedString("BeaufortScale_Description", comment: "BeaufortScale_Description"),
                         image: Image("blank"),
                         bottomLetter: " ",
                         buttonLetter: "About"),
    
    semaphoreButtonProps(headerText: "Alpha",
                         description: " ",
                         image: Image("a-alpha"),
                         bottomLetter: "A",
                         buttonLetter: "A"),
    
    semaphoreButtonProps(headerText: "Bravo",
                         description: " ",
                         image: Image("b-bravo"),
                         bottomLetter: "B",
                         buttonLetter: "B")
]
```

Big Thanks!

Comment: `semaphoreButtonPropsData` needs to be stored in `@State` for it to be mutable. You may want to consider adopting the standard Swift practices of capitalizing type names and starting variables/properties with lowercase letters.

Comment: @jnpdx 
Hello. Yes sure. You mean that i need to...

`struct semaphoreButtonProps: Identifiable {
    @State var id = UUID()
    @State var headerText: String
    @State var description: String
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for your data array to be mutable, it should be stored in `@State` in your `View`. Then, you can pass it via `Binding` to your child `View`.

*(I've also adjusted the capitalization of your types to fit the Swift conventions, so be careful to reflect that in your code if you copy/paste)*

```
public struct SemaphoreFlags: View {
    @State private var semaphoreButtonPropsData = [ //<-- Here
        SemaphoreButtonProps(headerText: "About",
                             description: NSLocalizedString("BeaufortScale_Description", comment: "BeaufortScale_Description"),
                             image: Image("blank"),
                             bottomLetter: " ",
                             buttonLetter: "About"),
        
        SemaphoreButtonProps(headerText: "Alpha",
                             description: " ",
                             image: Image("a-alpha"),
                             bottomLetter: "A",
                             buttonLetter: "A"),
        
        SemaphoreButtonProps(headerText: "Bravo",
                             description: " ",
                             image: Image("b-bravo"),
                             bottomLetter: "B",
                             buttonLetter: "B")
    ]
    
    public var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false){
            HStack{
                ForEach($semaphoreButtonPropsData) { $item in //<-- Here
                    SemaphoreFlagsButton(semaphoreButtonProps: $item) //<-- Here
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SemaphoreFlagsButton: View {
    @Binding var semaphoreButtonProps: SemaphoreButtonProps //<-- Here

    var body: some View {
        Button(action:{
            semaphoreButtonProps.buttonLetter = "\(Date())" //<-- Here

        }, label: {
            Text(semaphoreButtonProps.buttonLetter)
        })
            .frame(width: 100, height: 50 , alignment: .center)
            .background(Color(red: 0.29, green: 0.67, blue: 0.88))
            .cornerRadius(12)
            .padding(.leading, 8)
    }
}

struct SemaphoreButtonProps: Identifiable { //<-- Here
    var id = UUID()
    var headerText: String
    var description: String
    var image: Image
    var bottomLetter: String
    var buttonLetter: String
}
```

---

Update, based on asker's new information:

```
public struct SemaphoreFlags: View {
    @State private var headerText : String = "HEADER TEXT"
    @State private var semaphoreButtonPropsData = [ //<-- Here
        SemaphoreButtonProps(headerText: "About",
                             description: NSLocalizedString("BeaufortScale_Description", comment: "BeaufortScale_Description"),
                             image: Image("blank"),
                             bottomLetter: " ",
                             buttonLetter: "About"),
        
        SemaphoreButtonProps(headerText: "Alpha",
                             description: " ",
                             image: Image("a-alpha"),
                             bottomLetter: "A",
                             buttonLetter: "A"),
        
        SemaphoreButtonProps(headerText: "Bravo",
                             description: " ",
                             image: Image("b-bravo"),
                             bottomLetter: "B",
                             buttonLetter: "B")
    ]
    
    public var body: some View {
        Text(headerText)
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false){
            HStack{
                ForEach(semaphoreButtonPropsData) { item in //<-- Here
                    SemaphoreFlagsButton(semaphoreButtonProps: item, headerText: $headerText) //<-- Here
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SemaphoreFlagsButton: View {
    var semaphoreButtonProps: SemaphoreButtonProps
    @Binding var headerText : String

    var body: some View {
        Button(action:{
            headerText = semaphoreButtonProps.headerText
        }, label: {
            Text(semaphoreButtonProps.buttonLetter)
        })
            .frame(width: 100, height: 50 , alignment: .center)
            .background(Color(red: 0.29, green: 0.67, blue: 0.88))
            .cornerRadius(12)
            .padding(.leading, 8)
    }
}

struct SemaphoreButtonProps: Identifiable { //<-- Here
    var id = UUID()
    var headerText: String
    var description: String
    var image: Image
    var bottomLetter: String
    var buttonLetter: String
}
```

Or, an option that stores the ID of the selected item:

```
public struct SemaphoreFlags: View {
    @State private var selectedSemaphore : UUID? = nil
    @State private var semaphoreButtonPropsData = [ //<-- Here
        SemaphoreButtonProps(headerText: "About",
                             description: NSLocalizedString("BeaufortScale_Description", comment: "BeaufortScale_Description"),
                             image: Image("blank"),
                             bottomLetter: " ",
                             buttonLetter: "About"),
        
        SemaphoreButtonProps(headerText: "Alpha",
                             description: " ",
                             image: Image("a-alpha"),
                             bottomLetter: "A",
                             buttonLetter: "A"),
        
        SemaphoreButtonProps(headerText: "Bravo",
                             description: " ",
                             image: Image("b-bravo"),
                             bottomLetter: "B",
                             buttonLetter: "B")
    ]
    
    public var body: some View {
        if let selected = semaphoreButtonPropsData.first(where: { $0.id == selectedSemaphore }) {
            Text(selected.headerText)
        }
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false){
            HStack{
                ForEach(semaphoreButtonPropsData) { item in //<-- Here
                    SemaphoreFlagsButton(semaphoreButtonProps: item, selectedSemaphore: $selectedSemaphore) //<-- Here
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SemaphoreFlagsButton: View {
    var semaphoreButtonProps: SemaphoreButtonProps
    @Binding var selectedSemaphore : UUID?

    var body: some View {
        Button(action:{
            selectedSemaphore = semaphoreButtonProps.id
        }, label: {
            Text(semaphoreButtonProps.buttonLetter)
        })
            .frame(width: 100, height: 50 , alignment: .center)
            .background(Color(red: 0.29, green: 0.67, blue: 0.88))
            .cornerRadius(12)
            .padding(.leading, 8)
    }
}
```

Comment: So what do i do in the final to pass data to the Text() that is in the main Struct? Confused.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is "the final"? What is the "main Struct"? I showed, for example, how to set `buttonLetter` in the `Button`'s action. Is there something else you would like demonstrated?

Comment: Yes, please. See my code. I have `Text("HEADER TEXT")`. So the question is, how to make that text change on button click. The text depends on which button is clicked. `$semaphoreButtonProps.headerText`?

Comment: Okay -- see updated version